# Changing button text when asp.net collapsible panel expands or collapses

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using a button to show/hide an asp collapsible panel. How can I change the button's text to `show` when panel is collapsed and `hide` when it is expanded?

I tried using `TextLabelID="btnShowHideRequestComment" CollapsedText="Show" ExpandedText="Hide"` but didn't work.

```
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlRequestCommentHistory" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvwRequestCommentHistory" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="GridStyle" 
        DataSourceID="odsRequestCommentHistory">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="User" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CommentDate" HeaderText="Date" 
                SortExpression="CommentDate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Comment" HeaderText="Comment" 
                SortExpression="Comment" />
        </Columns>
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridAlternateRowStyle" />
        <RowStyle CssClass="GridRowStyle" />
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpeRequestCommentHistory" runat="server"
TargetControlID="pnlRequestCommentHistory" CollapseControlID="btnShowHideRequestComment" ExpandControlID="btnShowHideRequestComment"
Collapsed="true" CollapsedSize="0" TextLabelID="btnShowHideRequestComment" CollapsedText="Show" ExpandedText="Hide">
</asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found below solution from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1791338.aspx?On%20button%20click%20Change%20Text%20of%20button%20in%20CollapsiblePanelextender%20):

```
protected void btnShowHideRequestComment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            if (btnShowHideRequestComment.Text == "Show")
                btnShowHideRequestComment.Text = "Hide";
            else
                btnShowHideRequestComment.Text = "Show";
        }
    }
```